# MS-ACCESS: How to have a form write to a table through a join and/or union query

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, left-join, union

I have two JOIN queries in a UNION query. My form is based on the UNION query right now. Is there any conceivable way I can have the form write into a table through these queries? I had an operation to simply copy the content of the UNION query into a separate table, but I would like to not have to juggle data around like that.

Thanks

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: No. A UNION is not updatable.

Comment: please post your query too. Thanks.

Comment: What does it mean to update data through a union anyway? Why is there a union involved?

Comment: UNION is not updateable, and for good reason - which table would you update?